# problem with passing parameter between two django template using include

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have created a 'more_btn' component like this.

```
<div>
    <a href='{% url link %}' >{{ text }}</a>
</div>
```

and I want to reuse this component in two-parent components like bellow.

```
{% include "util_components/more_btn.html" with link="job1" text="s1" %}

{% include "util_components/more_btn.html" with link="job2" text="s2" %}
```

The problem is that the URL block in the 'more-btn' component wants an ID, not a string.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what are `job1` and `job2`? Are those proper names of URLs in your program?

Comment: yes, these are the names of my urls